# Why code with dot special form gives different results?

Tags: clojure

can you explain please? I don't understand, why the almost same code with dot special form and identity function has different results?

```clj
(. System getProperties) # => {"key" ...}
(. (clojure.core/identity System) getProperties) # => (err) No matching field found: getProperties for class java.lang.Class
```

I tried compare this:

```clj
(= (clojure.core/identity System) System) # true
```

and result is true

Comment: In general you can only replace `x` with `(identity x)` when it occurs in a context where no enclosing special form cares about the shape of `x`, i.e., when it is just being evaluated (and even then, you may lose type information). `.` is one example of a special form, and it cares about the shape of its first argument: for static methods it expects a symbol naming a class.

Comment: Also, you can just call `(System/getProperties)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static methods are special.

In the first case, the compiler sees that `System` is a class and treats `.` as a static method call ([source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/6975553804b0f8da9e196e6fb97838ea4e153564/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L1005)).

In the second case, it treats `.` as a regular call on an instance of some class, and `System` is an instance of class `Class`, hence that error.